# What does Clang-Tidy "suppressed X warnings" mean?

Tags: c++, clang-tidy

Here's my scan command (using .clang-tidy config):

```
clang-tidy <source_file> -- <a_bunch_of_include_files> <a_bunch_of_libraries>
```

I see the output for the source code, which is fine. At the very bottom I see:

```
Suppressed 30000 (30000 in non-user code). warnings
```

The source code uses multiple headers, and the source file is a small part of a very large and complex system. Does clang-tidy scan the include files and libraries as well? Where are these 30,000 warnings coming from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What does Clang-Tidy “suppressed X warnings” mean?

It means that there were X warnings that weren't shown because those warnings were produced from non-user sources.

> Does clang-tidy scan the include files

Yes. Clang-tidy pre-processes the source, and operates on the processed source which thus includes all the code from headers.

> Where are these 30,000 warnings coming from?

From the included sources.