# Clang-Tidy slow with dependencies

Tags: c++, clang, lint, clang-tidy, clang-static-analyzer

I am using clang-tidy to lint my code base, but the entire process is very slow. Is there a way to completely ignore header files and not only suppress the warnings? As you can see with this example, a ton of warnings are coming from my project dependencies:

```
Suppressed 72958 warnings (72958 in non-user code).
Use -header-filter=.* to display errors from all non-system headers. Use -system-headers to display errors from system headers as well.
```

Comment: How are you currently invoking clang-tidy?

Comment: loosely related: [Ignore system headers in clang-tidy](/q/46638293/11107541), [clang-tidy - ignore third party headers code](/q/61101056/11107541), [Is it possible to ignore a header with clang-tidy](/q/71797349/11107541), [How to use SYSTEM headers with CMake and clang-tidy?](/q/61196994/11107541)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a good way to avoid processing the headers at all, since clang-tidy needs to build the abstract syntax tree in order to run the static analyzer checks. That's just how [LLVM's LibTooling](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibTooling.html) (what clang-tidy is built with) works. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64360287/3712532) as well.

If speed is the problem (and you have multiple processor cores at your disposal), you can use [`run-clang-tidy.py`](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/clang-tools-extra/clang-tidy/tool/run-clang-tidy.py), which runs checks for each file in your compilation database in parallel.